# Wordpress. How to make or maybe what plugin I can use for changing some text in paragraph from admin panel in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

**Wordpress**. How to make or maybe what plugin I can use for changing some text in paragraph from admin panel in Wordpress?

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393/what-exactly-is-a-recommendation-question) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Theme and Plugin `.php files` can be [edited](https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_Files) using the built in admin panel editor.  If it is a theme, than I would suggest making a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and inserting your changes there so that they are not overwritten with each theme update.

Comment: It does not help in my situation.

Comment: Please elaborate on your question.  Your original question is vague and my answer fits your question.

Comment: In .php file I have some text in <p></p>, this text id not generated by php, it inserted in code. And how can I change it from admin panel.

Comment: Is the .php file part of a plugin or a theme?  If it is a plugin, you should be able to use the plugin editor within the plugins menu.  If it is a theme, than I would suggest making a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and inserting your changes there.

Comment: It just inserted in main page.

Comment: OK, it sounds like the .php file that you are dealing with is part of your theme.  See updated answer.

Comment: If this answer has been helpful, please consider accepting it.